# SharePoint List validation

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-addin, custom-list

I have ECO Submit Actual Date field, that if it is not blank (have some value) then process Status choice field should be changed to "Under Review".
What is the problem in the formula, I'm new to sharepoint 2013.

```
IF(NOT(ISBLANK([ECO Submit Actual Date]) [Process Status]="Under Review";
```

Comment: First: check your formula. You have 3 open brackets '(' and 1 closing ')'.

Comment: Calculated fields can only be used to set a value in the current field (the field the formula is on).

Comment: // [ProcessStatus] =  IF(NOT(ISBLANK([ECOSubmitActualDate])), "Under Review", "Initial")                                          I have tried this also.but not working. can u plaese make it correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented: "Calculated fields can only be used to set a value in the current field (the field the formula is on)". No value assignment is necessary in the formula, the result of the formula will be used as the field value.

Make sure the column `ProcessStatus` is a calculated column and enter the following formula:

```
IF(NOT(ISBLANK([ECOSubmitActualDate])), "Under Review", "Initial")
```

Comment: okay..Its done...it was not calculated column....Thank you very much...

Comment: Hello Dribbel, Im new to Sharepoint and using Infopath Designer for my list creation. i have requirement, in list i have 10 Date field, user has to select 1st date other 9 dates will be auto populate that i did.Now, problem is there is Days difference between 2 dates. like                "2Date is 1Date + 5. and 5 is business days only not saturday or Sunday. E.g 1date is 12/18/14 then after 5 days 2Date should 12/25/14. like that for all dates. Can u please give me logic for it.

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint Stack Exchange! Please post every question you have as a new question. Take the tour: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour